# How does WaitForDebugEvent[Ex] report a timeout?

Tags: winapi

The [WaitForDebugEvent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/debugapi/nf-debugapi-waitfordebugevent) and [WaitForDebugEventEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/debugapi/nf-debugapi-waitfordebugeventex) APIs allow a caller to specify a timeout. The functions return when a debug event occurred, or the timeout expired, whichever happened first. While the documentation describes how debug events are reported, there's no information at all on the APIs' behaviors in case of a timeout.

#### Questions

- How do the APIs report a timeout?
- Does this protocol hold for a value of `0` for `dwMilliseconds` as well?

Comment: GetLastError (this one's documented) will report ERROR_SEM_TIMEOUT in case of timeout. As for dwMilliseconds, I think it's like WaitForSingleObject that returns WAIT_TIMEOUT if the handle is not signaled after the time, whatever time you pass. ReactOS (and others) is written to follow exactly the same behavior as Windows (they use disasm, leaked Windows source, whatever...): https://doxygen.reactos.org/d5/d42/dll_2win32_2kernel32_2client_2debugger_8c.html#ac49f7f75ac42dd0c4e4677ee94b5f9e7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How do the APIs report a timeout?

The function returns `FALSE` and sets the last error to `ERROR_SEM_TIMEOUT`(0x79).

> Does this protocol hold for a value of 0 for dwMilliseconds as well?

Yes.

---

Since it's not documented we'll go with the implementation (I'm on Win 10).

[image]

Both `kernelbase!WaitForDebugEvent` and `kernelbase!WaitForDebugEventEx` APIs call the same piece of code (simply with a different arg).

In the shared piece of code the second call is made on `ntdll!DbgUiWaitStateChange` which itself is a simple wrapper around `ntdll!NtWaitForDebugEvent`.

On function return the code checks if the returned status is either `STATUS_ALERTED` (0x101) or `STATUS_USER_APC` (0xc0). If it is, it keeps calling the previous function (`ntdll!DbgUiWaitStateChange`), otherwise it checks if the status is an error (more precisely if the status is signed).

If it's not signed it checks that the status is `STATUS_TIMEOUT` (0x102). If it is, the NT Status is converted to a win32 error - from `STATUS_TIMEOUT` to `ERROR_SEM_TIMEOUT` (0x79) - and the function is exited.

---

Inside `nt!NtWaitForDebugEvent` (kernel level) we can have a good overview of what is happening with the [ReactOS source code](https://doxygen.reactos.org/da/dd4/dbgkobj_8c_source.html#l02001).

After a call to `nt!KeWaitForSingleObject` on the debug object the code checks ([source](https://doxygen.reactos.org/da/dd4/dbgkobj_8c_source.html#l02082)) what is the status of the call. If it is `STATUS_TIMEOUT` (which, if I'm not mistaken should happen in case of a 0 timeout), the function bails out and return the current status, which is, as explained above, converted to `ERROR_SEM_TIMEOUT` in userland.

```c
         Status = KeWaitForSingleObject(&DebugObject->EventsPresent,
                                        Executive,
                                        PreviousMode,
                                        Alertable,
                                        Timeout);
         if (!NT_SUCCESS(Status) ||
             (Status == STATUS_TIMEOUT) ||
             (Status == STATUS_ALERTED) ||
             (Status == STATUS_USER_APC))
         {
             /* Break out the wait */
             break;
```

Comment: *"which, if I'm not mistaken should happen in case of a 0 timeout"* - The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/nf-wdm-kewaitforsingleobject) seems to agree with that as well. One question remains, though: Do the APIs return `TRUE` or `FALSE` in case of a timeout?

Comment: @IInspectable : it returns `FALSE`. If you can read the assembler in the screenshot above the function sets `eax` to 0 before returning (happens at address ` `0x00007FF9B1C241D4` with the `xor eax, eax`),  just after converting the `STATUS_TIMEOUT` to `ERROR_SEM_TIMEOUT`.

Comment: Yep, I was in the process of modifying it. Thanks :)

Comment: fanny that `ERROR_SEM_TIMEOUT` set by win32 here on `STATUS_TIMEOUT`, despite `STATUS_TIMEOUT` converted (by `RtlNtStatusToDosError` ) to `ERROR_TIMEOUT` - this will be more waited code. but as is.